# How to escape backticks in Python3

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, escaping

I'm trying to escape backticks in Python. For an example, I have this string.

```py
>>> s = "my ` string"
>>> s
'my ` string'
```

Doing `` re.sub("`", "\`", s) `` will return `` 'my \\` string' ``.

How do I escape the backtick such that it will yield `` my \` string ``?

I need this because I will supply that string as an argument for a shell command, running inside a Jupyter Notebook.

```
! ./script.sh "$s"
```

Comment: Have you tried using doc strings? Not sure if it will work but trying enclosing everything within three double qoutes on each side like so ` """my \\` string""" ` and see if that works

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX I have, it will still yield ``'my \\` string'`` sadly.

Comment: ``.replace('`', '\\`')`` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks do not need to be escaped in Python. Your issue here is the backslash. This should be an easy fix, just change the second argument `` "\`" `` to `` r"\`" ``. This will turn it into a string literal, that way nothing will be auto-escaped.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
s = "my ` string"
for c in s:
    if c == '`':
        print(r"\`", end='')
    else: print(c, end='')
```

Output: `` my \` string ``

Comment: This works but isn’t as efficient as it could be, and has some bad practice. You wouldn’t want to get in the habit of using so many print statements like this in a larger program, *especially* using a new call for each individual character. Printing can be asynchronous and this could end up as spaghetti in a larger codebase!

Comment: @hryrbn Yes I am aware of that. But, in his case I guess it wouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib.
`password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)`